# Converting the current MS Word document to xml and saving it in a target file

Tags: xml, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I have built an MS word ADD in,in my add -in I want to build a feature which converts the currently opened document to xml and saves this xml in a separate file.

But i want this conversion to happen with a specific DTD file.I 'am able to convert , but not according to the required DTD standards,also this conversion seems to be having errors.Any help is much much appreciated.This is what I tried so far:

private void button_convert(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {

```
       Word._Document oDoc;
        oDoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        //Creating the instance of Word Application
     object Target = @"c:\\abc\\Target.XML";
         object Unknown = Type.Missing;
       // Specifying the format in which you want the output file 
         object format = Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument;
        //Changing the format of the document
        oDoc.SaveAs(ref Target, ref format,
                ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                ref Unknown, ref Unknown);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I 'am able to convert , but not according to the required DTD standards

What standards are you talking about?

It looks like you need to apply XSLT for getting the required XML document. Word doesn't provide anything for that.

Comment: Thanks Eugene.Standards are custom DTD followed in my workplace.I'll look into XSLT too.